# Jquery Change attr of val before appending

Tags: jquery, attr

I have a textarea field where users can enter an youtube embed code, then on submit i grab the val of the textarea and append it to body. I want to add ?id=123 to the end of the src in the embed code before i append it to body. What is the easiest way to do this. The appended value should be the iframe code with the modified src

Embed code looks like

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aemXgP-2xyg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

## UPDATED CODE

```
                var value = $('textarea').val();
                var wmode = '?id=123';
                var value1 = $(value).attr("src", $(value).attr("src") + wmode);                 
                var code = $('<div class="abs embed" id="embedId">' + value1 + '<span class="move"></span></div>');                 
                $(code).appendTo(...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var iframe = $($("textarea").val());
iframe.attr("src", function(i,v) { return v + '?id=123'; }).appendTo("body");
```

(updated with Šime Vidas' solution)

edit: if you have firebug, on this page, you can copy/paste the iframe code in a textarea, and run this code in the console:

```
var lol = $("textarea").val()
var iframe = $(lol);
var test = iframe.attr("src", function(i,v) { return v + '?id=123'; })
test.appendTo("body");
```

And the youtube video should be inserted at the end of the page.

edit 2: To do what you want in your update, try that:

```
var value = $('textarea').val(),
wmode = '?wmode=transparent',
value1 = $(value).attr("src", $(value).attr("src") + wmode),
span = $('<span class="move"></span>'),
div = $('<div class="abs embed" id="embedId"></div>');
div.append(value1).append(span).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: I want to append the whole iframe code including the modified src attribute and not just src.

Comment: @alex The whole iframe will be appended to the BODY. Using `attr()` just modifies the src attribute

Comment: All jQuery methods are chainable, so iframe.attr(blablabla).appendTo() will append the iframe.

Comment: I don't want to append right away. The want to set the result of var iframe with the modified src to var newvar then use $(newvar).appendTo... But this is not working. var newvar = iframe.attr("src", function(i,v) { return v + '?id=123'; }); $(newvar).appendTo('body');

Comment: First, iframe.attr() return a jquery object, so you shouldnt need to do $(newvar).appendTo, you can just do newvar.appendTo. But it should still work. I just tried in firebug on this stackoverflow page, and it works...

Comment: yes it's returning an object. I posted the code i'm working with. See updated code above.

Comment: The problem in your code is that you concat value1 as if it was a string, but it's a jQuery object.

Comment: That works, I was indeed concatenating a jquery object as a variable. Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 2):

```
var code = $("#TEXTAREA").val();
var appCode = $(code);
appCode.attr("src", appCode.attr("src") + "?id=123").appendTo($("#parentDiv"));
```

Comment: Better: `appCode.attr('src', function(i,v) { return v + '?id=123'; })`

Answer (score 0):

All the posted solutions are good and work but i would prefer to just cut out the src if it exists and then look if it is realy a valid video source. If you let them input html, you are going to risk much!

Look at Facebook, you can enter a link,and he will recognize what it is, and it is much nicer for the user, if he can just pass in the youtube link, not searching for the whole embed code! Safety first!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(ta.value).attr('src', function(i,v) { return v + s; }).appendTo('body');
```

... where `s` is the string that you want to add to the src attribute
... and `ts` the TEXTAREA element